# Very noob Python question about optimising some nested for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am *very* new to Python, and have just have just got a small piece of code working to compile some user data into a single file. But since I am only learning, I don't just want it to run, but to actually use the functionality Python provides. For reference, here is the part of the code I think can be made faster.

In short, I have a list of usernames in a text file and usage data for each user over a 4 month period in a CSV for each day.

The logic is

```
loop over each CSV:
    loop over each line in that CSV:
         loop over the list of usernames:
               if the username matches, append the user data for that user
```

The inner two for loops are what I am really focussing on improving, since that is where there is a bit of a bottleneck given the number of users. In what follows, username_list is a list that I read from the text file and read_csv is a list that is read from the csv file. The working code is as follows:

```
#Initialise a dictionary of lists to store the final data and read the keys (which are the usernames)
main_data = {}
with open(".\\listofusernames.txt") as usernames:
     username_list = usernames.read().splitlines()

for user in username_list:
    main_data[user] = []

#Loop over the CSV files with usage data for each day for 3 months
for i in range(1,91):
    csvdir = f".\\csvfiles\\usagedata_{i}.csv"
    with open(csvdir, 'r') as daily_usage_csv:
         read_csv = list(csv.reader(daily_usage_csv))

#Nested loops over the username list and CSV to get the data for the correct user
for user in username_list:
        for line in read_csv:
             #Username is stored in the first column of CSV so we do an if statement on index 0 of the line
             if line[0] == user:
                 #Usage data is in the second and third column of the CSV, so we append index 1 and 2
                 main_data[user].append(line[1])
                 main_data[user].append(line[2])
                 break
```

The place where I really want to optimise is in the inner two for loops, over the email list and the lines in the CSV. I was hoping to do this usings Python's maps() function rather than an explicit for loop. The issue is that the object I am iterating over is not indexing the thing I am appending, so I am not sure how to implement that.

Can anyone give some simple tips for how to make the loops faster here?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need two for loops. You need only one, and that is to iterate over the csv for usage data.
And then check if `line[0]` ie `user` is already present in the dictionary`main_data`. And then insert to `main_data`.

```
for line in read_csv:
    if line[0] in main_data:
        main_data[line[0]].append(line[1])
        main_data[line[0]].append(line[2])
```

Comment: Thank you Albin, this is helfpul. Although I am not sure if I can use that here exactly as written. The purpose of of the loop is not to check if it is there, but rather to match the right line in the CSV with the correct user. The user is definitely there since the username list contains all users. I will have a bit more of a think about it though. Perhaps I should also read the CSV into a dictionary so I can just match the keys?

Comment: based on your idea, I decided to read the CSV as a dictionary and do a lookup instead of a loop. It is much, much faster, so thank you, that was a brilliant idea.